# inline svg, if using switch, hml content of foreignobject in not displayed

Tags: css, svg

Switch statement does not display the text.
If i use foreignobject without switch - it is working.
If i try to create a fallback to the foreignobject, svg is displayed in correct height and width, but without the text.

```
<svg class="txtOnImgSvg sport" viewBox="0 0 700 100" >
    <foreignobject class="txtOnImgSvgFO sport" x="20" y="20"  >
        <div class="txtOnImgSvgFOdiv sport" >Sport : <br>50m simming pool on site, <br>Tennis court, <br>Fishing <br>Cycling <br>Diving.</div>         
    </foreignobject>
</svg>

<svg class="txtOnImgSvg sport" viewBox="0 0 700 100" >
     <switch>

         <foreignobject class="txtOnImgSvgFO sport" x="20" y="20"  >
              <div class="txtOnImgSvgFOdiv sport" >Sport : <br>50m simming pool on site, <br>Tennis court, <br>Fishing <br>Cycling <br>Diving.</div>         
         </foreignobject>

         <text class="txtOnImgSvgTxt sport" x="20" y="20"  >
             <tspan x="20" y="20" class="navDescr" >Sport:</tspan>
             <tspan x="20" y="100" class="navDescr" >50m simming pool</tspan>
             <tspan x="20" y="100" class="navDescr" >tennis court</tspan>
             <tspan x="20" y="180" class="navDescr" >fishing</tspan>
             <tspan x="20" y="180" class="navDescr" >cycling</tspan>
             <tspan x="20" y="180" class="navDescr" >diving</tspan>
         </text>  

    </switch> 
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't see any relevant attribute on any of the child components. Are you sure you use the `switch` element correctly?

Comment: The reason was misspelled `foreignobject`. Shall be `foreignObject` to work.

Comment: Seems OK on Firefox provided you add width and height attributes to the foreignObject element.